# How to return to top of a while loop after an error

Tags: python-3.x

i have a code in while loop which might blow up sometimes **but** can be fixed  with changing a variable usually by adding a number to it.
for example i have a list of 100 phone numbers and 52th number is currently unavailable which can cause an error and stop the whole program.
how should i rewrite this example code to skip the numbers that can cause an error and rerun from while with a new variable:

```
phoneNumberlength:100
callthisnumber:1
try:
    while callthisnumber <= phoneNumberlength:
        callfunction(callthisnumber)
except:
    callthisnumber = callthisnumber + 1
    #what should i write here to return to that while loop?
```

Comment: Sounds like you want a `try` block inside a `while` block, instead of vice versa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `try`/`except` inside of the `while` loop instead of the other way around:

```
while callthisnumber <= phoneNumberlength:
    try:
        callfunction(callthisnumber)
    except:
        callthisnumber = callthisnumber + 1
```

Although you should be using a `for` loop here instead of while:

```
for callthisnumber in range(1, phonenumberlength + 1):
    try:
        callfunction(callthisnumber)
    except:
        pass
```

And you can clean this up with [`contextlib.suppress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.suppress):

```
import contextlib

for callthisnumber in range(1, phonenumberlength + 1):
    with contextlib.suppress(ValueError):
        callfunction(callthisnumber)
```